# MarLogic dls functions module uri

Tags: nosql, marklogic

I am new to MarkLogic and I cannot find a way to do module invoke instead of adhoc query for using `dls:document-insert-and-manage`.
I have a content source connected to my host and port.

```
Session session = contentSource.newSession();
Request request = session.newModuleInvoke("marklogic.com/xdmp/dls/MarkLogic/dls.xqy)
```

Does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dls module is a library module. It provides a set of functions that you can call. You need to import it into a main module (or require it into a JavaScript module) and then call the function you want.

Comment: How do I add the library module in the javascript module? Also, what exactly is javascript module?

Comment: @mholstege is talking about [`Server-side JavaScript (SJS)`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/getting-started/javascript). She means DLS is server-side code, which you cannot import client-side, so you have to run code on the server to use it, either XQuery or SJS..